# «Ко всему прочему» — особенности пунктуации

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

1. *Он был **ко всему прочему** зол — ведь ему пришлось раньше времени бросить свой бильярд* ([И. Рэнкин. Чёрная книга](https://knizhnik.org/ien-renkin/chernaja-kniga/12)).
2. *Противники Трампа уверены, основания для импичмента есть, и **ко всему прочему** — их целых два* ([Ю. Рогулев. Холостой выстрел](https://iz.ru/618856/iurii-rogulev/kholostoi-vystrel-impichmentom)).

Поначалу я "споткнулась" о первое предложение, когда читала книгу; засомневалась.
(Освежила в памяти правило: ["КО ВСЕМУ ПРОЧЕМУ, вводное сочетание"](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_360).)

Потом "попалось" второе — из статьи. Я ещё больше засомневалась.
(Очень хочется обособить "ко всему прочему" в обоих случаях — как вводное.)

Хотелось бы понять: правильна ли пунктуация в предложениях?

Answer (score 3):

> *Он был **ко всему прочему** зол — ведь ему пришлось раньше времени бросить свой бильярд.*
>
> *Противники Трампа уверены, основания для импичмента есть, и **ко всему
>   прочему** — их целых два.*
>
> Хотелось бы понять: правильна ли пунктуация в предложениях?

Правильна.

Из *"Справочника по пунктуации"* на [**Грамоте.ру:**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_360)

> @ Слова «ко всему прочему» в знач. «в дополнение к остальному» обычно
>   не обособляются: *Но еще **ко всему прочему** знаете что я подумал
>   перед самым мгновением этим?..* Ю. Герман, Дорогой мой человек. ***Ко
>   всему прочему*** обнаружилась и удивительная пластичность. В. Аксенов,
>   Новый сладостный стиль.

Хотя можно *ко всему прочему* и обособить. Ошибки тоже не будет.

Вот что говорится о выражении ***ко всему прочему*** в "Словаре вводных слов" Остроумовой и Фрамполь:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Дело в том, что правило на "Грамоте" я видела (на неё я ссылаюсь в вопросе). Мне она _показалась_ неубедительной. А всё-таки: Вы сами поставили бы запятые?

Comment: Поставил бы? Не знаю. Решение зависело бы от контекста. От того, выделил бы я это выражение вводной интонацией при его прочтении в составе контекста.

Answer (score 2):

Наречное выражение ***ко всему прочему*** обособляется по общим правилам. Если вы (как автор, к примеру) хотите, чтобы оно являлось вводным, то есть было выделено, подчеркнуто или использовалось в качестве дополнительного замечания, то  его надо поместить в такое место, где оно **плохо вписывается в структуру предложения, не составляет его основного содержания, как бы является "лишним"** (обычно это начало предложения или определенная позиция в середине). В противном случае оно будет  необособленным наречием.

1) Он был **ко всему прочему** зол — ведь ему пришлось раньше времени бросить свой бильярд. Здесь предложение делится  тире на две части, это основное интонационное деление, обособлять "ко всему прочему" при такой структуре и мало распространенной первой части неудобно.

Сравнить: Он был, ко всему прочему, еще и  зол — ведь ему пришлось раньше времени бросить свой бильярд. Распространили предложение, и "ко всему прочему" можно уже обособить.

2) Противники Трампа уверены, основания для импичмента есть, и ко всему прочему — их целых два. А здесь обособляется **присоединительная конструкция** со своей структурой и интонацией  (союз И - присоединительный), тире обозначает паузу.

Примеры:

**Ко всему прочему** обнаружилась и удивительная пластичность. [Василий Аксенов. Новый сладостный стиль (2005)]

**Ко всему прочему,** Алексей клятвенно обещал обеспечить меня работой. [Ю. И. Андреева. Многоточие сборки (2009)] Ведь предприятие, **ко всему прочему,** должно заработать деньги, а налоговая нагрузка на бизнес тоже немаленькая.

**И ко всему прочему** ― горбун-смотритель, неотступно следующий за отважными экскурсантами. [Самый, самая, самое // «Знание - сила», 2009]

Comment: Приведенные примеры лишь доказывают тезис Грамоты: "ко всему прочему" не обособляется только в в знач. "в дополнение к остальному".

Comment: Я придерживаюсь немного другой точки зрения. Очень часто в функции вводного слова наречие практически не меняет смысла или меняет его незначительно, и тогда основным фактором становится структура предложения. Автор так формирует эту структуру , чтобы было ясно, хочет ли он обособить наречие как вводное слово или нет. Даже составители правил иногда признаются, что значения у наречия и вводного слова различаются не всегда.

Answer (score 0):

То, что пишет Грамота, меня убеждает. Вопрос в том, как различать это два случая. По-моему, *ко всему прочему* в первом предложении может пониматься и как вводное, и как "в дополнение к остальному", а вот во втором предложении — только как вводное.

Comment: В первом предложении без обособления просматривается двусмысленность: зол ко всему, кроме любимого бильярда.

Comment: Тогда надо писать так: Ко всему прочему, он был зол — ведь ему пришлось раньше времени бросить свой бильярд.