# Предложение из правила. Нет ли ошибки?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сложное-предложение, правила

Когда-то на сайте я задала вопрос [“Ко всему прочему” — особенности пунктуации](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/435489/%D0%9A%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8).

В вопросе есть [**правило**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_360), в котором в качестве примера приводится предложение Ю. Германа ("Дорогой мой человек"):
**Но еще ко всему прочему знаете что я подумал перед самым мгновением этим?..**

Есть это предложение и в [словаре-справочнике по пунктуации](https://punktuaciya.academic.ru/355/%D0%BA%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83).

Мне кажется, что в указанном предложении есть пунктуационная ошибка — не хватает запятой. Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Запятой перед "что" не хватает?

Comment: Да, Артём, мне так _думается._ В таком виде предложение присутствует во всех правилах.

Comment: Да, меня тоже удивило, что её нету! Согласен.

Answer (score 4):

У Розенталя разбирается эта тема: ***знаете что я подумал*** –  здесь значение, близкое **к  частице.**

Розенталь, п.8  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122#pp122

Он, знаешь, человек обязательный — вводное слово; **А нам за это знаешь что будет?** — близко к частице; Потом лето было знаешь какое!; Там знаешь какое положение?; Нас знаешь сколько, болельщиков!; Я нашёл в углу знаете что?; Магомет знаете что наделал? (Пог.);
Я, видишь, всё это уже испытал — вводное слово; А бабка Варвара видишь что делает? — близко к частице.

Answer (score 0):

Как верно сказала Sharon, данное сочетание близко к вопросительной частице, и это действительно так. Чтобы Вы лучше меня поняли, приведу пример:

*Знаешь что он сделал?*

В данном случае частица "знаешь что" использована не просто так. Сравните с аналогичным:

*Что он сделал?*

Не знаю, заметили ли Вы чёткую разницу, но в первом случае нам интересно не само действие, совершенное определенным человеком, а осведомленность об этом спрашиваемого лица, причём, как правило, мы уже знаем, что произошло. То есть данная частица, хотя и является вопросительной, необходима больше для эмоциональной окраски.

Нельзя забывать, что данное сочетание не всегда является частицей. Так, это возможно в повествовательных предложениях, где есть главная и придаточная части.

Как, опять же, отметила Sharon, это сочетание,   конечно, не является единственным 
исключением. Например, существует такой оборот, как "видишь что".