# Узнать что делать

Tags: пунктуация

Нужны ли знаки препинания? Что перед нами?
Это сложноподчиненное предложение с придаточным изъяснительным и союзным словом "ЧТО"?
Это неразложимое сочетание с подчинительным союзом или союзным словом в составе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Розенталя в § 41. Цельные по смыслу выражения — примером служит "найти что делать". Запятая не ставится.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/49.htm (см. §107, примеч. 2, п. в)

Неполное придаточное предложение не отделяется запятой только в одном случае: если оно усечено *до одного только союзного слова*:

> -- Следователь что-то на нас имеет - зачем ты ему звонил?
>
> -- Узнать *что*.

Соответственно, в вашем случае запятая *нужна*.

Comment: Посмотрите [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/452175/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%9d%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8/452177#452177). Может, и в этом вопросе сомнения по такому же поводу.

Answer (score 0):

***Узнать, что делать.***

Запятая ставится. Это действительно  сложноподчиненное предложение с придаточным изъяснительным и союзным словом ЧТО.

Сомнения возникают в связи с тем, что это сочетание имеет обобщенное значение: *как быть, что предпринять.* Но и эти выражения тоже будут отделяться запятой.

Пример:

Скоро к нам пришли Саша Романов и Витя Коротаев, **что делать, спрашивают**. Я **не знАл, что делАть.** [Виктор Астафьев. Затеси (1999) // «Новый Мир», 2000]

Прибежал **узнать, что делать**. Судя по его растерянной физиономии, Советник умыл его как следует. Ну ничего. [Максим Милованов.  (2000)

Comment: То есть выходит, что цельным по смыслу выражением Розенталь считал именно фразу "найду что делать"? И "узнать (,) что делать" - уже не тот случай? Если сопоставить предложенную вами главу из пособия и параграф 41, о котором говорилось выше?